# Spring Mvc serve .jsp as part of url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to convert my legacy app to spring and we have a mvc module where the url will http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index**.jsp**

previously that page used to get load from  of web.xml and when i converted my app to spring mvc config, when accessing the url with index.jsp its throwing 404. I can make a url with /index and render the index.jsp file using spring which wont show the .jsp in the url. but my problem is the clients whoever saved the url with .jsp gets error..

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.app")
public class ClientWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


public class ClientWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx
          = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ClientWebConfigurer.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(
          "client-dispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
     }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"that page used to get load from of web.xml"*? Usually, JSP files are served by the Servlet container simply by having the JSP file in the deployed .war file, not because it is mentioned in the web.xml file.

Comment: Usually, for a URL like `/index` to be served from a Spring webapp, you need a `@Controller` class with `@GetMapping("/index")` method. I see no such code in the question.